# How to flag first object with duplicated property in array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array like this:

```
 var myArray = [
    {id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
    {id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
    {id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
    {id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
    {id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'joe@ocean.com'},
    {id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
    {id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
 ];
```

I need to flag which element is first with equal 'entry_id' and 'name', so result should be like this:

```
 [
    {id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com', isFirst:false},
    {id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com', isFirst:false},
    {id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'joe@ocean.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:false},
    {id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:false},
 ];
```

What I've already tried:

```
function updateArray() {
    myArray.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.isFirst = false;
      myArray.forEach((item2, j) =>{
        if (item.entry_id == item2.entry_id && item.name == item2.name && i < j ) {
          item.isFirst = true;
        } else if (!item.isFirst) {
          item.isFirst = false;
      }
   })
 })
 return myArray;
}
```

The result I get is next:

```
 [
    {id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com', isFirst:false},
    {id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com', isFirst:false},
    {id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'joe@ocean.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
    {id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:false},
 ];
```

Is there a best approach rather then use 2 loops?

Thank you for help!

Link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/88p5p5oj/30/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hash table for collecting the wanted group's first flags in a single loop.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com' }, { id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com' }, { id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com' }, { id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com' }, { id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'joe@ocean.com' }, { id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com' }, { id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com' }],
    keys = ['entry_id', 'name'],
    hash = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(o => {
    var key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    o.isFirst = !hash[key];
    hash[key] = true;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return `myArray` once you find and set the first match. Or you could just return the array index where you found it and use that.

If you need the `isFirst` property to be set on each object (because it does not exist in that object otherwise) and you want that done in the loop, then just change your code to something like this:

```
function updateArray() {
    var foundFirst = false;
    myArray.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.isFirst = false;
      myArray.forEach((item2, j) =>{
        if (!foundFirst && item.entry_id == item2.entry_id && item.name == item2.name && i < j ) {
          item.isFirst = true;
          foundFirst = true;
        } else {
          item.isFirst = false;
      }
   })
 })
 return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses an object called `visited` to get a track of the already checked elements.

*This example has two objects with name 'Jenny Block'*

```js
var myArray = [    {id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},    {id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},    {id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},    {id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},    {id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'},    {id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},    {id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'}, ],
    visited = {};
   
myArray.forEach(c =>  {
  var key = `${c.entry_id}|${c.name}`;
  c.isFirst = !visited[key];
  visited[key] = true
});
console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your function to something like this.. *Disclaimer.. this does assume your json will be ordered.*

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'},
  {id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
];

function updateArray() {
  var prevItem = "";
  myArray.forEach((item, i) => {
       item.isFirst = item.entry_id != prevItem;
       prevItem = item.entry_id;
  });
  return myArray;
}

console.log(updateArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a helper object to iterate your array. For every element that exists in the array set `isFirst` to `false`. If an element isn't in the `helper` object, add it to the helper, and set `isFirst` to `true`.

Clone the original object with [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) or  [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and add `isFirst`.

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com'},
  {id: 5, entry_id: 3, name: 'Joe Ocean', email: 'joe@ocean.com'},
  {id: 6, entry_id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 7, entry_id: 3, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
];

const helper = Object.create(null);
const result = myArray.map(function(o) {
  const key = `${o.entry_id}-${o.name}`;
  const isFirst = helper[key] ? false : (helper[key] = true);

  return { ...o,  isFirst };
});

console.log(result);
```